# Laravel error when trying to create new project

Tags: laravel

Hello i am just new to laravel,i went through the installation process and everthing seems to run well, but when i run the comand to create a new project i receive an error but it looks like the new project is created.

i suppose i have to install some packages but i am not sure this is what prompt out after creating a new proyect.
[image: laravel error]

I also have composer and node.js well installed.

When i opened the new project in vscode i found that laravel did not create a vendor file. and when i run php artisan it prompt the following error.

C:\FreeCodeGram>php artisan

PHP Warning:  require(C:\FreeCodeGram/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\FreeCodeGram\artisan on line 18

Warning: require(C:\FreeCodeGram/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\FreeCodeGram\artisan on line 18
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'C:\FreeCodeGram/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\FreeCodeGram\artisan on line 18

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\FreeCodeGram/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\FreeCodeGram\artisan on line 18

Comment: Don't post image of text as this is not searchable. Post it as plain text

Comment: you are wright. i thought it could have a easy solucion to someone with a little knowledge in laravel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue can be fixed by installing the extension it is saying

To enable FileInfo extension, you need to edit your php.ini and change a single line.

Locate the line:

`;extension=php_fileinfo.dll`

Remove the starting comment:

`extension=php_fileinfo.dll`

The location of you php.ini seems to be located at: C:\php\php.ini

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Location should be determined by checking output of `phpinfo()`. Also enabling module may require httpd restart

Comment: the file was created but without the vendor file. for that reason i am not able to use php artisan command. i posted the error that is prompted when i write the command php artisan, but i dont know what it needs

Comment: The second error means the system is failing to give permission where you are trying to install the files and then failing completely to install it.
You may need to either install it in a different folder or give the proper rights to the filesystem access that folder.